# Can someone help me this?

Tags: c++

How can i put for loop inside switch case and also it only get the last number I input

```
    switch(choose)
    {
    case 1:

        cout << "How many number you want to input? ";
        cin >> num;

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            cout << "Input a number" << "(" << i << "): ";
            cin >> choose;
        }
        root = Insert(root, choose);
        cout<<"\nElements in data are:";
        Inorder(root);
        break;
```

Comment: Could you restate the question? It is not clear what "he only gets the last number i input" means. Just pasting a piece of code would not help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move

```
root = Insert(root, choose);
```

inside the `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
    cout << "Input a number" << "(" << i << "): ";
    cin >> choose;
    root = Insert(root, choose);
}
```

#### Suggestion for code improvement

Create a function to read the numbers and add them to the list.
Call that function under the `case` clause.

```
switch(choose)
{
  case 1:
    root = readInput(root);
    break;
```

Assuming `root` is of type `Node*`,

```
Node* readInput(Node* root)
{
    cout << "How many number you want to input? ";
    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        cout << "Input a number" << "(" << i << "): ";
        cin >> choose;
    }
    root = Insert(root, choose);
    cout<<"\nElements in data are:";
    Inorder(root);

    return root;
}
```

Comment: It will not get any input to user it will go automatically to the question sir

Comment: @sjidasj, I don't see why that would happen. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are only inserting after the for loop finished, which means you will have only inserted once. You need to use Insert() inside the for loop.